# How to access same account using SSH and RStudio server with an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio-server

I'm trying to create a tutorial to teach users how to use a command line software package that we've developed with RStudio to analyze a preset collection of data files. To do this, I want to create AMI that comes with a directory that contains a number of files and is pre-loaded with the necessary software including RStudio server. To install RStudio server, I've been following [Randy Zsitch's](http://randyzwitch.com/r-amazon-ec2/) instructions and I'm able to login to RStudio using the user account. However, if the user is logged into RStudio, they can't see the default home directory (i.e. `/home/ubuntu`), their home directory (i.e. `/home/rstudio`) only has the `R` directory. I could certainly install the data files for the tutorial into `/home/rstudio`. However, if they SSH into the default account to access the command line software then they can't get the `rstudio` account without using `sudo`.

I'm looking for help to achieve one of two options...

- Enable user to SSH into the EC2 instance using the `rstudio` account and password and access RStudio server with the `rstudio` account. Currently, I can seem to do this
- Enable user to access RStudio server with the `ubuntu` account. This doesn't seem possible since the log in uses key-pair and not a password making it impossible to access RStudio server with a password since there isn't one.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but I'm still pretty new to the world of AWS. How do I set things up so that someone can directly log into the same account using RStudio server and SSH?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the command line tools and how/where you're installing them? It sounds like you want to install those somewhere everyone can reach them (e.g. into `/usr/local/`) rather than into a specific user's home directory.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan - I've tried to be more specific. It isn't so much access to the command line tools as access to the data and the ability to access the same account by SSH and RStudio server.